# QuillJS relative urls

Tags: quill

Is it possible in **quilljs** use a relative path (like in tinymce) for images?

When you have backend and frontend in different folders or domains this is usefull to correctly display images in backend keeping relative url.

I mean: 
In backend (subdomain.domain.tld)

Insert a relative image: /somefolder/someurl/image.jpg

Real url of the image is: domain.tld/some.../image.jpg

Result: Image not displayed.

What i need: Insert relative image and get displayed on quill using full url, but keep only relative.

Comment: I would think different domains would call for an absolute URL and Quill supports both so maybe I'm misunderstanding the question? Otherwise you can try relative works on quilljs.com by opening the console and running `quill.insertEmbed(0, 'image', 'assets/images/users/slack.png')` and observe that it works

Comment: Updated the question with more information.